# sudo command executes without prompting for password

Tags: sudo, password, root

For some reason, I suddenly do not need to enter the password when issuing `sudo some_cmd`.

Entered command just runs without ever prompting password, even if I am not logged in as user root. Commands that need root privileges still need to be invoked with `sudo` though. I am on Ubuntu 10.04.

Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: "Commands need root password still need to be invoked with sudo though" - I have problems understanding that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, sorry if any confusion, what i meant is that for certain commands, you will still need to do `sudo cmd` instead of just `cmd`. But now `sudo cmd` does not ask me for password any more.

Comment: Marius Ducea seems to explain all options for sudo settings very well in this article. It covers the topic of PASSWD/NOPASSWD etc.
Refer link below:
http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/18/linux-tips-password-usage-in-sudo-passwd-nopasswd/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say `sudo -K`, then retry your test. If it starts asking again, all that was happening is that you had `sudo` configured to remember your password for some time.

On top of this, Ubuntu's default `sudo` configuration makes it remember your credentials across `tty`s. This affects `ssh` sessions, as you've discovered, since each new `ssh` connection looks like a new terminal to the low-level OS code.

This also affects things like the graphical Terminal app. If you authenticate with `sudo`, then create a new tab with Ctrl-Shift-T, you'll find that you don't need to give a password to `sudo` again in that tab, despite the fact that it also creates a new `tty`. You can even close the Terminal app entirely, and as long as you restart it within the normal password timeout, `sudo` will run without requiring you to re-enter your password. This behavior may be enough to make you decide you want to keep this feature enabled.

Mac OS X works this way these days, too.

Not all *ixes do.  Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and derivatives like CentOS) insist on getting the password on each new `tty`.

You can disable both behaviors by changing the `Defaults` line in `/etc/sudoers` to something like this:

```
Defaults=env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0,tty_tickets
```

- The `env_reset` bit should be there already, and isn't relevant here
- The `timestamp_timeout` directive tells it to immediately time out each `sudo` session. It's like saying `sudo -K` after every normal `sudo` command.
- The `tty_tickets` directive ensures that it associates credentials with the `tty` they were used on, not just the user name. This is supposed to be the default already, and is documented as such on Ubuntu, but they must have built their distribution of `sudo` to disable this option, for the convenience reasons given above.

Comment: `sudo -K` works, but i wonder why `sudo` remember my password for some time even if i log in using a fresh ssh session (after quitting the previous session in which `sudo` was issued).

Comment: @MLister you can override that using the sudoers arguments, as the answer here states.  Add `timestamp_timeout=0` to the `Defaults=` line in `/etc/sudoers` and it will prompt for the password for every `sudo` command.

Comment: @MLister it's how Ubuntu makes things look user-friendly. What it is security-wise is another story.