# Security of sudo not asking for a password after the first time

Tags: security, sudo

After using `sudo` and entering a password to do so, `sudo` remembers that we have entered a password and we do not have to enter a password the next time we use it.

I am concerned about the possibility of using this fact to trick a user (admin/sudoer) to execute a script that contains a `sudo` command, so that the script can use administrator privileges.

**A test using a directory and ls**

I figured I could probably show that a script would ask for a password so that this trick could not work. I did the following test.

I created a directory testDir owned by root and using `chmod` I deleted all the access priviliges of both the group (g) and others (o). I used `sudo` to do so, so from now on assume we are in the "remember that the user does not need to enter a password to use sudo" state.

In testDir I created a testFile using `sudo` (after this we don't need to enter a password to use sudo anymore).

Because I am not root, `ls testDir` now tells me that permission is denied.

However, `echo sudo ls testDir| bash` prints testFile to the terminal.

The behavior appears to be the same if instead of piping "sudo ls testDir" to bash, we execute a shell script containing the line `sudo ls testDir`.

**Questions:** Should you use caution when executing programs when you have just used `sudo`?

Comment: I think it really depends on what script you are talking about. If one has sudo access, I don't think one would execute a script without knowing what it does, especially when normally it would require sudo access.

Comment: @ryekayo yeah, for simple script that seems reasonable. But I do not see how things are any different for larger applications that are not so easy to oversee. For example I might download some application that I do not completely trust, thinking it would not be too bad if the application can potentially use the privileges of that specific user. But if I then accidentally start it up from a terminal where "sudo is active", then it can suddenly do anything. I guess this is surprising to me, hence my effort to disprove that this was the design.

Comment: i understand where you are coming from. You should look into this O'Reilly book that can go into the specifics of Linux Security.. It's called Linux Security Cookbook..

Comment: If it concerns you, you can always [revoke the password manually, and/or change the `timestamp_timeout` parameter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80289/65304)

Comment: @ryekayo thank you for that reference, that sounds interesting. I would prefer to have a good "intermediate level unix book" where the author warns me of cases like though. I feel this is something everybody who uses `sudo` should know about. I will start using the -k option a lot I think.

Comment: steeldriver thank you, I had been looking for that exact functionality.